# strerror(errno) return "Invalid argument" when call read() & write()

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, fcntl

I try to access a file in android by native method, but i got  "Invalid argument" after call read or write function. The **data_ptr** is align to 512 bytes and it is declared as byte array in java.

**JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL**

```
Java_com_aa_bb_NativeRead(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz, jbyteArray data_ptr, jint length){
    int ret=0;
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data_ptr);
    jbyte *body = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data_ptr, 0);
    fd = open(filePath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ret = read(fd, body, length);
    if(ret<0){
        LOGE("errno: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data_ptr, body, 0);
    return ret;
}
```

**JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL**

```
Java_com_aa_bb_NativeWrite(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz, jbyteArray data_ptr, jint length){
    int ret=0;
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data_ptr);
    jbyte *body = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data_ptr, 0);
    fd = open(filePath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ret = write(fd, body, length);
    if(ret<0){
        LOGE("errno: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data_ptr, body, 0);
    return ret;
}
```

**Edit:**

If I use `open(filePath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);` the error is disappear. But i want to use **O_DIRECT** for ignore cache&buffer to access hardware directly.

Comment: And did the `open()`s succeed?

Comment: always (!) check the result of any open() function for success

Comment: Yes, open() is succeed. In the real function, i separate the open to anther function.

Comment: Is `body` 512-byte aligned? Is `length` a multiple of 512 bytes? Are you sue that `GetByteArrayElements` will always return correctly aligned memory? Why do you want to use `O_DIRECT` anyway? "for ignore cache&buffer to access hardware directly" is not an explanation of why you want to use it, it's just restating what the flag does, but not why you want to do it.

Comment: the len(it is data_ptr's length) is always multiple of 512 bytes. GetByteArrayElements I cannot sure...  http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-bypass-the-OS-buffering-during-I-O-in-Linux     I reference this link, which answered by Robert Love to add the O_DIRECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O_DIRECT` requires writes to be multiples of the underlying filesystem:

> The  `O_DIRECT`  flag  may  impose  alignment  restrictions on the length and
>        address of user-space buffers and the file offset of I/Os.  In Linux align‐
>          ment restrictions vary by filesystem and kernel version and might be absent
>          entirely.  However there is currently no  filesystem-independent  interface
>          for  an  application  to  discover  these  restrictions for a given file or
>          filesystem.  Some filesystems provide their own interfaces  for  doing  so,
>          for example the `XFS_IOC_DIOINFO` operation in `xfsctl(3)`.
>
> Under  Linux  2.4, transfer sizes, and the alignment of the user buffer and
>          the file offset must all be multiples of the  logical  block  size  of  the
>          filesystem.  Under Linux 2.6, alignment to 512-byte boundaries suffices.

`GetByteArrayElements` provides no such guarantees. It merely returns the address of the base of the primitive array of elements - in this case that's the address of the bytes in the byte array. These are allocated by the Java memory manager. You'll either have to copy the bytes (defeating the object of `O_DIRECT`), remove `O_DIRECT` or use some other strategy for allocation of the memory (such as allocating them yourself with `mmap(..., MAP_ANON)`).

Comment: Thanks for your explain! Could you please give me some hints of using mmap(..., MAP_ANON)?  Because I need to pass the memory which allocated in java.

Comment: Please use quote formatting for quotes, and code formatting for code.